# Почему переменная answer не получает значение

Tags: php, post, form, форма

form2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="action2.php" mathod ="POST">
     <fieldset>
      <legend>Каким языком программирования является PHP?</legend>
      Структурным
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="structure"><br>
      Процедурным
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="procedure"><br>
      Объектно-ориентированным
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="OOP"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
     </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

action2.php

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
     $answer = $_POST['type'];
 }
 else {
     $answer = NULL;
 }
 echo "answer = $answer<br>";
 if ($answer != NULL) {
     if ($answer == "OOP") echo "Правильно!<br>";
     else echo "Неправильно!<br>";
 }
 else {
     echo "Вы не выбрали вариант.<br>";
 }
```

Выводится:
answer = 
Вы не выбрали вариант.

Почему переменная answer не получила значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас в форме прописано mAthod="POST", вместо mEthod="POST"